# Angular2 Debug in Chrome

Tags: angular

I am a begginer, I have a doubt when I debug. 
Because the breakpoint , first passes through line 44, and then the 32 ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

That's because of the async nature of HTTP requests in JavaScript. The code in the `subscribe` callback gets called as soon as the HTTP request comes back with a response.

The code below the `subscribe` call therefore gets called before the callback, because the HTTP request has not finished yet.